# How to use ProbabilityDistribution for a posterior expression

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am performing a Bayesian updating on a Lognormal prior. After combining the prior and likelihood and dividing by the normalization constant I get the following expression as the posterior:

```
(0.805745 E^(-7.05*10^6 t - 0.255194 (15.576 + Log[t])^2))/t
```

I now want to use this as a distribution:

```
pdist = ProbabilityDistribution[posterior, {t, 10^-12, 10^-5}];
```

So far ok. I can now plot with the distribution

```
LogLinearPlot[PDF[pdist, t], {t, 10^-11, 10^-6}, PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"Failure Rate (f/hr)", "PDF"}]
```

But I cannot take the mean, Mean[pdist], or variance etc, they just return the input. Trying RandomReal[pdist] returns the following:

```
RandomReal::udist: The specification is not a random distribution recognized by the system
```

What am I missing in the assignment of the expression to ProbabilityDistribution[].

Clay

Comment: Check out "Create your own distribution" [on this page](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/mathematics-and-statistics.html)

Comment: @ssch There does not appear to be anything overtly wrong with the OP's set up of the custom distribution.

Comment: To the OP ... is there a reason your density is numerical/approximate .. rather than setting it up as an exact symbolic algebraic entity? That goes for the bounds of the domain of support too.

Answer (score 1):

To take a random sample from a distribution you want [`RandomVariate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomVariate.html) as opposed to [`RandomReal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomReal.html), not that it works right away in this case:

```
posterior = Rationalize[(0.805745 E^(-7.05*10^6 t - 0.255194 (15.576 + Log[t])^2))/t ]
pdist = ProbabilityDistribution[posterior, {t, 10^-12, 10^-5}];
pts = RandomVariate[pdist, 1000];
pts // DeleteDuplicates // Length
(* 1 so it gave the same number a thousand times*)

pts = RandomVariate[pdist, 1000, WorkingPrecision -> 100];
pts // DeleteDuplicates // Length
(* 1000 this seems better *)
```

Always good to have a look at the quantile plot:

[image: quantile plot]

But to get `Mean`, `Median`, ... to work properly you usually have to define your own distribution, often it is easier to use `NIntegrate` and `FindRoot` applied to the definitions of the properties. Together with interpolations of the cdf and inverse cdf this tends to be quite quick.